# Google map loading slowly

Tags: google-maps

would it would help to have the apikey linked to an account that also has other Google services for the company associated with it, like Analytics, etc. also does the sensor variable speed up the call as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [v2 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/), you will need an API key from the [Maps API Sign Up](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/signup.html) site. However note that the v2 API has been officially deprecated as of May 19, 2010, and you are encouraged to use the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/) instead. The v3 API does not require an API key.

As for the [sensor parameter](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/basics.html#SpecifyingSensor), no, it will not make the map load faster.